# NPM installation on a completed project

Tags: npm, npm-install

Do I need to run npm install/npm build on a completed project from github which has all of the dependencies in the node_modules already once I pull it?

Comment: You must not commit node_module on the repository. You need to have a package.json and a package-lock.json which describe dependencies.

Comment: I am asking in case the modules are already there

Comment: so delete the node_module directory and run npm install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to remove node modules folder **(for ubuntu)** using `sudo rm -rf node-modules`

and then run command `npm install`
This will install all the required dependencies for the project, and then your'e good to run project.